# Opening a text file through a plugin

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-model, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm trying to open a text file through a plugin to get timestamps and positions for keyframes of a model animation. I'm opening the file using **ifstream()**. Unfortunately no matter where I place the text file it won't be opened by the plugin. What can I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12631/opening-a-text-file-through-a-plugin/) by [pap-x](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2424/pap-x/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 50 on 2016-02-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-02-17**:
Have you tried using the file's full path? Does that work?

**Comment by [pap-x](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2424/pap-x/) on 2016-02-18**:
Yeap! Full path did work, thank you! (Had tried that already but I was missing something probably)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I also use an external file for my current project. Here is the code:

```
std::ifstream f(path.c_str(), std::ios::in);
```

Here, path is a std::string object. Be ware that the path is relative to the folder where you run gazebo, NOT relative to the folder of your plugin. If you know exactly where you run gazebo, then adapt your path or you can use an absolute path, as chapulina said.

---

Originally posted by [debz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1306/debz/) with karma: 198 on 2016-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2